# How to debug mysql_query() function in php

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

Regards,

I am new to PHP. Here is a small login script that i wrote for a login page. It checks username and password from the database.

```
 <?php

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","saw","gehriroute");

if(mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "could not connect to the database";
    exit;
}
else
{
    echo "database runing <br>";
}

$uname = trim($_POST['uname']);
$password = trim($_POST['password']);

echo "username and password are $uname and $password <br>";

$query =  "select count(*) from login where username = '".$uname."' and password = '".$password."' ";



$result = mysqli_query($query,$con);

if(!$result)
{
    echo "query failed";
}



$row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
$count = $row[0];

if($count > 0 )
{
    echo "yes your are logged in";
}
else
{
    echo "wrong username or password";
}

?>
```

It is not having issues connecting to the database but it is not responding either. I bet the script dosnt pass the mysql_error() function. I tried to debug it using `mysql_error()` function, it returned nothing. What are the other things i can use to debug and correct the error ?

Output:

> ```
> database runing
> username and password are ateev and saw
> query failed
> ```

Comment: try changing the mysql_ functions to mysqli

Comment: after select query....do echo $query;...and check it into database

Comment: You're mixing `mysqli_XXX` and `mysql_XXX` functions. You have to be consistent. And you have the arguments backwards for `mysqli_query`.

Comment: `ini_set('display_errors', 'on'); error_reporting(E_ALL);` ?

Comment: Not the answer but you should escape the $_POST data before putting it in the query using [mysqli_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) to prevent SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Yea this code is really insecure and it also looks like you are storing passwords in plaintext too. I'd advise using prepared statements and switching to PDO as well if you want more security.

Comment: @Sam  Seriously? is that my problem? I appreciate that but simple query isn't running. I will add security later.

Comment: @user1263375 It will be a problem if someone tries to do even a basic sql injection on you lol.

Comment: wow never been encouter that error before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not first run the SQL first via either the command line or through the workbench?

Then this will enable you to make sure that the query is valid and you are getting the expected results.

**EDIT**

Also if you read [mysqli_query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) manual page the line

```
$result = mysqli_query($query,$con);
```

is incorrect and should be

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
```

Comment: I said that before but hey noone pays attention to my answer :p

Answer (score 1):

Could try this:

```
if (!mysqli_query($link, $query)) { //if the query fails find the error
    echo mysqli_error($link);
}
```

Comment: Semi colon is not a must at the end of that query. You suggested that in your answer and now its removed :)

Answer (score 1):

Let's Try this code. It works now.

```
<?php

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","saw","gehriroute");

if(mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "could not connect to the database";
    exit;
}
else
{
    echo "database runing <br>";
}


$uname = trim($_POST['uname']);
$password = trim($_POST['password']);

echo "username and password are $uname and $password <br>";

$query =  "select count(*) from login where username = '".$uname."' and password = '".$password."' ";

$result = mysqli_query($con,$query);   // Connection link should first

//echo "Error: ".mysqli_info();

$count = mysqli_num_rows($result);    // Get Count row like this..

if($count > 0 )
{
    echo "yes your are logged in";
}
else
{
    echo "wrong username or password";
}

?>
```

Comment: Oh dear god are you mixing object with procedural style

Comment: $result->num_rows; is object oriented it should be like mysqli_num_rows($result); to match the rest of the code. Also the only problem he had was mixing up the query and connection in mysqli_query I think.

Comment: @lemondrop : yes you are right. I correct my mistake. Thanks for your key.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add after your query.This will check/determine wether your query is executed succesfully or returned an error

```
$result = mysqli_query($query,$con);

if(!$result){
  // means your query failed
  // error checking...
   printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($con));
}
else {
   echo 'query executed.';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the php script isn't being called. try setting your .php file to just `echo 'x';` and see if `x` gets outputted. if not, then your calling the wrong script and need to specify the right filename (eg: *myScript.php*).

heres a [working example of what your trying to do](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php). just replace `SELECT Code, Name FROM Country ORDER BY Name` with your query.

happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

> Echo $query ; exit

copy Query and run it in to Your Query Executer !

you will get the SQL error if any

other wise Query will run successfully.

Comment: I did this. it displayed : select count(*) from login where username = 'ateev' and password = 'saw'   Which runs fine after adding semicolon to the end.